# Error after login with Azure Active Directory in spring boot : The parameter 'scope' is duplicated

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

Following is the error message I am getting after login

[image: This is the error page]

I followed the steps from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory) to create a basic application. I added the server details in **application.yaml** file after converting to **https** since azure requires **https**

Following is my **application.yaml** file

```
server:
    port: 443
    ssl:
        key-store: keystore.p12
        key-store-password: randomword
        keyStoreType: PKCS12
        keyAlias: tomcat

spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        enabled: true
        profile:
          tenant-id: <tenant-id>
        credential:
          client-id: <client-id>
          client-secret: <client-secret>
        redirect-uri-template: https://localhost:443/login/oauth2/code/
```

for login I am using **https://localhost/** and it redirects me to the following (I have placed ... in place of long alpha numeric parts)

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&state=...%3D&redirect_uri=https://localhost:443/login/oauth2/code/&nonce=...&sso_reload=true

After successful login, I get redirected to that first screen with **invalid_request** error having the url **https://localhost/login?error** and in the backend I am getting the following error message

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AccessToken.getScopes()" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.getAccessToken()" is null

I have not added any extra layer of security or any code

Comment: Please if possible downgrade the "spring-cloud-azure-dependencies" to version 4.3.0, maybe also spring boot to "2.6.11".

Comment: @BBacon Yes it's a version issue, we ended up using  a sample project found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/?source=recommendations. This was the project: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in